# Data Switching and Information Leakage

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, randomness, pseudo-random-function

Hypothesis: Let $z,a$ be uniformly random elements of a field $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p$ is a large prime number. Also, let $(-z)$ be additive inverse of $z$.

---

I have a fixed secret value $x$. I mask it as $I=x+z$ and send it to a semi-honest server.

Later on, I send $w$ and $c=(-z)\cdot w+a$ to the server, and ask it to do as follows: 
$K=I\cdot w+c=(x+z)\cdot w+(-z)\cdot w+a=wx+a$.

**Question:** Given $I, w,c$ and $K$, can the server learn anything about $x$?

---

Note 1: $z,a$ are secret values, too. So if the server learns about them it may learn about $x$.

Note 2: The above scenario is a part of protocol and it may not make sense for the readers at first glance.

Comment: $K$ seems to be superfluous, as it can be computed from $I$, $w$ and $c$.

Comment: @cygnusv Yes, you're right. I wanted to say that $K$ is the final result that the server computes for me.

Comment: If $w=0$ then $c=a$, but no information about $-z$ and hence $x$ is given by knowing $c$. Otherwise $w\ne 0$ allows you to write $a = c+zw$ as well as $z=w^{-1}(a-c)$ showing that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $a$ and $z$ for any choice of $c$ and $w(\ne 0)$. This is consistent with the fact that both $z$ and $a$ are drawn uniformly from $\mathbb{F}_p$. I do not know now, how to finish the proof that the server learns nothing about $x$, but it should follow from the one-to-one correspondence between $z$ and $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server receives three messages:

1. $I=x+z$. This is the value $x$ encrypted with a one-time pad $z$. The server cannot find $x$ without knowing (something about) $z$.
2. $w$. This is (presumably) independent of anything secret.
3. $c=(-z)\cdot w+a$. This is the value $(-z)\cdot w$ encrypted with a one-time pad $a$. The server receives no information about $(-z)\cdot w$ and thus $z$ or $x$ without knowing something about $a$.

Therefore, assuming that $z$ and $a$ are generated randomly just for this instantiation and never reused or revealed, and that $w$ is independent of $x, z, a$, the server learns nothing about $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm wondering why you didn't say anything about the result $K=wx+a$. In the result $a$ cannot be considered as a one time pad (as it has been before).

Comment: So my question is Why does not $K$ leak any information about the secret values?

Comment: @user153465, since $K$ is calculated from the other values, it cannot leak any extra information.